# Setting path for cookies in CEF?

Tags: c#, cefsharp, chromium-embedded, cookiemanager

With the [recent breaking changes](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2743) in Chromium framework and CEF the method `ICookieManager.SetStoragePath()` has been removed. I didn't find the way how to set this path properly now. 
I need to set it once for all cookies, and previously I was using the following start-up code:

```
        var settings = new CefSettings();
        settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-gpu", "1");

        Cef.Initialize(settings);

        Cef.GetGlobalCookieManager().SetStoragePath(this.pipeName, true);
```

What is the expected way of setting this path now?

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/2622/implement-support-for-networkservice#comment-51303489

Comment: You need to set the CachePath to persist cookies https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/blob/cefsharp/75/CefSharp.MinimalExample.WinForms/Program.cs#L27